# Chasing Two Rabbits

Tags: idiom

While reading old Question: [Two birds with one stone?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/5024/1982) I was reminded of the Russian expression: "A man who chases two rabbits will catch neither."

In English we speak of the futility of "fighting on two fronts". This may have been born from experiences of Twentieth-Century total-war. There was Germany (1914), despite the Schlieffen Plan, fighting on two fronts. A generation later (1944), there was Germany fighting on three fronts.

Three rabbits?!

The Romans, with a huge Empire to police: "local difficulties"; insurrections here; uprisings there; diluting their resources; moving armies; firefighting--how were the inherent difficulties of "chasing two (or more) rabbits" expressed?

A wild guess: "si duos cuniculos persequeris, neutrum capies." =

"If you pursue two rabbits, you will catch neither."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Publius Syrus expressed that very thing in *[Sententiae](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=AyMTAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA14&lpg=PA14&dq=Lepores%20duo%20qui%20insequitur&source=bl&ots=U61xL4pWTZ&sig=ACfU3U2IZG7GdntrVd-d3LQzEcFlAJhvmQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiBtrSAh_3sAhV6DrkGHVk-CDg4ChDoATAOegQIBxAC#v=onepage&q=Lepores%20duo%20qui%20insequitur&f=false)*:

> Lepores duo qui insequitur, is neutrum capit.

Comment: @Expediti Bipes: Thank you. Is this where the Russians got it from?

Comment: @tony. I don't know, but it seems very likely to me.

Comment: @tony Would seem like a mighty big coincidence if not!

Comment: @tony See the discussion on Russian.SE: https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/19886/7386

Comment: @Sebastian Koppehel: Is there a German equivalent of this expression, I'd be surprised if there isn't?

Comment: @tum_: Thanks. I studied Russian at school; sadly I've forgotten too much of it.

Comment: @Expedito Bipes: In the Q. recommended by tum_, contributor, yellow sky, the quote is: "duos insequens lepores, neutrum capit", attributed to Erasmus. As always, it can be difficult to prove who original progenitors were.

Comment: @tony. Erasmus compiles a book of proverbs or sayings, the "Adagiorum", and, in it, he provided a Latin translation of a Greek proverb. However he did so at a date long after Publius Syrus included this saying in Sententiae. The saying probably did, in fact, orignate with the Greeks.

Comment: @tony I was completely unaware of it, but Google shows plenty of hits for "Wer zwei Hasen jagt, fängt keinen", which is as straightforward a translation as anyone could wish for; attributed, curiously, to all kinds of origins (Japan, Hungary, Confucius, "an old proverb"). It may be just as well not to catch the rabbit, because: Der eine schießt den Hasen, der andere frißt den Braten (as Diocletian [reportedly complained](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/sha/carus.shtml): *ego semper apros occido, sed alter utitur pulpamento*).